# Why isn't my ImageView link displaying via Intent?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap, imageview

I'm loading an Image into an ImageView using a link, and I'm trying to pass this link from one activity to display on another activity by an Intent. However, the Image just seems to come up blank.

Below I have listed the code associated with the two activities, as well as the adapter of the RecyclerView that the information is being passed from in the first activity

ActivityOne.java

```
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

...


    mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Se%C3%A1n-Haughey.S.1987-04-25/image/large");

...

 @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAME", mNames.get(position));
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGE", mImageUrls.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

ActivityTwo.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_members_map_detailed);

        tvMemberName = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberNameDetailed);
        tvMemberParty = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberPartyDetailed);
        tvMemberConstituency = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberConstituencyDetailed);
        tvMemberAddress = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberAddressDetailed);
        tvMemberEmail = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberEmailDetailed);
        tvMemberPhone = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberPhoneDetailed);
        tvMemberContributions = findViewById(R.id.tvClareMemberContributionsDetailed);

        imgMember = findViewById(R.id.imgClareMemberImageDetailed);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mName = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAME");
        String mParty = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PARTY");
        String mConstituency = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_CONSTITUENCY");
        String mAddress = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_ADDRESS");
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGE"));
        String mEmail = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_EMAIL");
        String mPhone = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PHONE");
        String mContributions = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_CONTRIBUTIONS");


        tvMemberName.setText(mName);
        tvMemberParty.setText(mParty);
        tvMemberConstituency.setText(mConstituency);
        tvMemberAddress.setText(mAddress);
        tvMemberEmail.setText(mEmail);
        tvMemberPhone.setText(mPhone);
        tvMemberContributions.setText(mContributions);
        imgMember.setImageURI(myUri);
```

Adapter information associated with Image

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
            .into(holder.image);

    holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

    holder.party.setText(mParties.get(position));
```

Comment: `imgMember.setImageURI(myUri);` – That's not going to work. Why don't you just use Glide again to load that in `ActivityTwo`, like you did in the `Adapter`?

Comment: How would I do that in the intent? I'm not sure how that is coded?

Comment: Well, it's nothing to do with the `Intent`, really. You're already doing that part correctly, as far as I can see. Assuming that the `"EXTRA_KEY_IMAGE"` is being passed successfully, in `ActivityTwo`, retrieve that extra as a plain `String`, instead of parsing it to a `Uri`. Then, instead of the above-mentioned `setImageURI()` call, you would do pretty much the exact same thing as you are in the `Adapter` – `Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(myUri).into(imgMember);`.